# proving the identity for subgroups.

Tags: abelian-groups, normal-subgroups

What is the best way to prove that if a  group is a subgroup of some other group? Or more precisely how to prove that they have common identity element?

Comment: Let $G,*$ be a group and $H\subset G$, then $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if and only if $H,*$ is a group. So you can simply prove that $H\subset G$ and $H$ is a group. If $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, then they automatically have the same identity element.

Comment: And how can I find the identity of the Subgroup?

Comment: Let $e_H$ denote the neutral element of $H$ and $e_G$ the neutral element of $G$. Then $e_H=e_G*e_H$ since $e_G$ is the neutral element of $G$ and $e_H\in H\subset G$. But also $e_H=e_H*e_H$. Hence $$e_H*e_H=e_G*e_H.$$
Let $(e_H)^{-1}$ denote the inverse of $e_H$ in $G$, multiplying the above equation by this inverse we find that $e_H=e_G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $e$ be the identity of $G$ and $e'$ be the identity of $H$.

Then $e'e'=e'$ in $H$.

This also holds in $G$ because the multiplication in $H$ is the restriction of the multiplication in $G$.

Multiplying by the inverse of $e'$ in $G$, we cancel $e'$ on both sides to get $e'=e$.